# Is there multiplatform lock in Kotlin?

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, thread-safety, kotlin-multiplatform

What multiplatform Lock or synchronization approach should be used in **multiplatform** Kotlin code? Previously in Java code i used `synchronized` and i can see [`synchronized`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/synchronized.html) in Kotlin too. However it's marked as Deprecated and will be removed from `common` std lib soon.

I can see [`withLock`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.concurrent.locks.-lock/with-lock.html), but it's supported on **JVM** only, not multiplatform.

Any thoughts?

PS. For now we don't want to migrate to Kotlin coroutines because of too much rewrite and coroutines library footprint (too large for Android library with strict disk footprint requirements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Kotlin/Native Concurrent documentation ([here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/concurrency.html)):

> **Concurrency in Kotlin/Native**
>
> Kotlin/Native runtime doesn't encourage a classical thread-oriented concurrency model with mutually exclusive code blocks and conditional variables, as this model is known to be error-prone and unreliable. Instead, we suggest a collection of alternative approaches, allowing you to use hardware concurrency and implement blocking IO. Those approaches are as follows, and they will be elaborated on in further sections:
>
> - Workers with message passing
> - Object subgraph ownership transfer
> - Object subgraph freezing
> - Object subgraph detachment
> - Raw shared memory using C globals
> - Coroutines for blocking operations (not covered in this document)

It seems that locks are not exposed in Kotlin/Native by design. There *are* implementations (see [Lock.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/concurrent/Lock.kt)), however that class is marked `internal`.

*However*, there is a multi-platform implemenation of locks in KTOR (very limited [doc](https://api.ktor.io/1.1.3/io.ktor.util/-lock/index.html), [source code](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/master/ktor-utils/common/src/io/ktor/util/Lock.kt)). It is public, but marked with [`@InternalApi`](https://api.ktor.io/1.1.3/io.ktor.util/-internal-a-p-i/index.html), which may affect its stability.

You might also be interested in this KotlinLang discussion thread: [Replacement for synchronized](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/replacement-for-synchronized/11240)

Answer (score 4):

There is no lock nor synchronized in Kotlin common. Kotlin's approach is to use immutable data. You can add your own expect AtomicReference in common and actual implementations in JVM Native, it will help a lot. Also keep in mind that coroutines in Native are single threaded at the moment. Also you can't share mutable state between threads in Native.

Comment: thanks for the "immutability" suggestion, I had an issue with concurrent modifications of a hash map, so returning a new HashMap solved the problem...

Answer (score 3):

There is full "lock" multi-platform implementation in  Kotlin coroutines library. It is based on atomicfu and I think that can be easily extracted from there, even if you really don't want to depend from the full coroutine library:

- [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html#mutual-exclusion)
- [reference](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/index.html)
- [source code](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/sync)

Comment: > "can be easily extracted from there". How can it be done without copy/paste?

Comment: These implementations are coroutine-specific, and it is not easy to "extract" some part of them imho...

Answer (score 0):

The best available multiplatform solution is [kotlinx-atomicfu](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-atomicfu), a member of the official Kotlin libraries.
See its [locking features](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-atomicfu#locks):

> `kotlinx.atomicfu.locks` package providing multiplatform locking primitives that require no additional runtime dependencies on Kotlin/JVM and Kotlin/JS with a library implementation for Kotlin/Native
>
> - SynchronizedObject is designed for inheritance.
> - ReentrantLock is designed for delegation.

Although it is currently in beta status, it is already used by production-quality libraries like *kotlinx-coroutines* and *arrow-kt*.

It is a low-level library, based on a Kotlin compiler plugin, so it is not always easy to use, for example its versions are bound to specific Kotlin versions.