# Is there a thread-safe way to memoize a Kotlin Sequence?

Tags: kotlin, thread-safety, sequence, memoization

I have a method which generates a sequence:

```kotlin
    fun createFactorSequence(decimalMode: DecimalMode): Sequence<BigDecimal> {
        var sign = BigDecimal.ZERO - BigDecimal.ONE
        return createAllFactorialsSequence()
            .filterIndexed { i, _ -> i % 2 != 0 }
            .map { n ->
                sign = -sign
                sign * BigDecimal.ONE.divide(n, decimalMode)
            }
    }
```

Because the sequence will be the same between multiple invocations, it seems like it should be possible to cache it (I would have to key that by the decimal mode, in its current form, but there may be ways to remove the need for that).

I have seen some code out in the wild which attempts to implement a memoized sequence, recording the elements from the underlying sequence into a list so that the next invocation wouldn't need to recompute them.

They mostly work along these lines (I've simplified it to assume the sequence is infinite):

```kotlin
    fun <T> memoizedSequence(slowSequence: Sequence<T>): Sequence<T> {
        val slowIterator = slowSequence.iterator()
        val cachedEntries = mutableListOf<T>()

        return sequence {
            var index = 0
            while (true) {
                // TODO: Not thread-safe!!
                while (cachedEntries.size < index) {
                    cachedEntries.add(slowIterator.next())
                }

                yield(cachedEntries[index])

                index++
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem, as commented, is that this is not thread-safe. If two threads come through at the same time and each get an element from the iterator, there's no guarantee that the entries will end up in the list in the same order.

But I can't just use Java synchronization to get around it, because the library is multiplatform.

Is there a Kotlin way to do this?

I attempted to use `Mutex` (I'm not even sure whether adding a dependency on coroutines is going to be acceptable) but found that I'm not allowed to call `Mutex.withLock` from inside `sequence {}`.

Comment: I think coroutines are Kotlin's solution to multi-threading, so it doesn't provide any other mutual exclusion tools for multi-platform. Relevant discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56882860/is-there-multiplatform-lock-in-kotlin), although OP is either wrong or outdated with respect to `synchronized` being deprecated, because it isn't for Kotlin-JVM. I think your question can be more generalized. Sequences are one of many types of objects in Kotlin that are not thread-safe.

Comment: You can check atomicfu project: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.atomicfu#locks

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah, the crappy thing in this particular situation is that the library in question has no dependencies right now, and doesn't do any multithreading itself at all (otherwise it would already have the dependency). But, whoever uses the library (or any given library) might be doing multithreading themselves, so unfortunately we still have to think about thread safety. I don't think I said anything about deprecation, though. Also, I knew I could generalise the question, but I didn't want to rule out any possible solution that might solve it for sequences only.

Comment: I see why Sequences are interesting specifically actually. If it was some other type of collection you could just tell the user to synchronize it themselves externally, but that’s not a good solution for something that is lazily creating its elements.

Comment: @Tenfour04 also because infinite Sequences are apparently less commonly used, a bunch of the solutions out there just say to collect the whole sequence into a List and then use the list.

Comment: @Hakanai I'm not sure if this is exactly the case here, but Kotlin supports multiple targets, each with its own approach to concurrency: JVM threads, native threads, single thread, coroutines. Maybe this is why common stdlib doesn't provide any utils related to concurrency or synchronization (or maybe I'm wrong?) - such utils really depend on your specific needs and chosen targets. Atomicfu kind of fills the gap here, although we still need to use it with care, because e.g. it is improper to use it with coroutines as it blocks threads (this is my assumption, I never used it).